# EOF Batch error

Tags: batch-file, cassandra, eof, cqlsh

Impossible to run a batch alter table in cqlsh.

```
cqlsh:test> create table mytable (id int PRIMARY KEY, comment text);
cqlsh:test> begin batch alter table mytable add testcol text; apply batch;
SyntaxException: <ErrorMessage code=2000 [Syntax error in CQL query] message="line 1:50 missing EOF at 'apply' (... mytable add testcol text; [apply] batch...)">
```

Each time I try to make a batch, I've the same EOF error, on different systems.

Answer (score 1):

According to information in [CQL for Cassandra](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/batch_r.html) docs, `ALTER TABLE` statement is not allowed:

> A `BATCH` statement combines multiple data modification language (DML)
>   statements (`INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`) into a single logical
>   operation...